# SQL syntax error after FROM (other_query)

Tags: sql-server

So I'm trying to run this query on my sql server database:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp)
FROM (SELECT TOP (20) timestamp
    FROM CPPM_03ChannelCountErrors 
    WHERE '2015-03-10 00:00:00' < timestamp AND timestamp < '2015-03-15 00:00:00' AND skuid = '3252' 
    ORDER BY timestamp)
```

And I get this error message: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near ')'."

I have already confirmed that this query by itself works just fine:

```
SELECT TOP (20) timestamp
FROM CPPM_03ChannelCountErrors
WHERE '2015-03-10 00:00:00' < timestamp AND timestamp < '2015-03-15 00:00:00'
AND skuid = '3252'
ORDER BY timestamp
```

I'm grateful if someone figures this out. It's driving me insane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp)
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (20) timestamp
    FROM CPPM_03ChannelCountErrors 
    WHERE '2015-03-10 00:00:00' < timestamp 
    AND timestamp < '2015-03-15 00:00:00' 
    AND skuid = '3252' 
    ORDER BY timestamp
) tmp
```

Every subquery needs an alias name. I added it and named it `tmp`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp)
FROM (SELECT TOP (20) timestamp
    FROM CPPM_03ChannelCountErrors 
    WHERE '2015-03-10 00:00:00' < timestamp 
      AND timestamp < '2015-03-15 00:00:00' AND skuid = '3252' 
    ORDER BY timestamp) t --<-- you need to alias the sub-query here
```

Comment: Why are you using a subquery with a top 20? It looks like you can just use a select max with a single select. Anyway both Juergen and Ali are correct if you want to do it with a sub-query.